# Apagar registro que está sendo duplicado na query com o inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo uma consulta ao meu banco de dados e nessa consulta eu utilizo um INNER JOIN para unir duas tabelas!

Porém estou com um problema, pois não sei manipular muito bem o JOIN, e isto está gerando um pequeno problema.

No meu banco atual estou unindo a tabela relação com produto, dessa forma a união é de N para 1, e mesmo que fosse de 1 para N o resultado seria o mesmo.

O problema é que como a união está sendo feita de N valores para 1, o produto está sendo duplicado N vezes, se o produto em questão tiver 10 características o produto será duplicado 10 vezes.

Acredito que isso seja causado devido minha falta de experiência, dessa forma não estou sabendo montar a QUERY de forma correta!

Gostaria então de saber como evitar essa duplicação de valores, ou então como excluir todos os produtos repetidos e deixar apenas um.

Esse é um pequeno exemplo das tabelas.

```
+----------------------+
| PRODUTOS             |
+----+-----------------+
| ID | NOME            |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | Caneta          |
+----+-----------------+
| 2  | Lapiseira       |
+----+-----------------+

+----------------------+
| CARACTERISTICAS      |
+----+-----------------+
| ID | VALOR           |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | AZUL            |
+----+-----------------+
| 2  | NOVA            |
+----+-----------------+
| 3  | BIC             |
+----+-----------------+
| 4  | ESCREVE         |
+----+-----------------+
| 5  | 10G             |
+----+-----------------+

+-------------------------+
| RELACAO                 |
+----+---------+----------+
| ID | ID_PROD | ID_CARAC |
+----+---------+----------+
| 1  |    1    |     1    |
+----+---------+----------+
| 2  |    1    |     2    |
+----+---------+----------+
| 3  |    1    |     3    |
+----+---------+----------+
| 4  |    1    |     4    |
+----+---------+----------+
| 5  |    1    |     5    |
+----+---------+----------+
| 6  |    2    |     1    |
+----+---------+----------+
| 7  |    2    |     2    |
+----+---------+----------+
| 8  |    2    |     3    |
+----+---------+----------+
| 9  |    2    |     4    |
+----+---------+----------+
| 10 |    2    |     5    |
+----+---------+----------+
```

Na hora de listar o resultado, o nome do produto aparece a mesma quantidade de vezes que o numero de característica que o mesmo possui!

```
+------------------------------+
| RESULTADO                    | 
+-------+----------+-----------+
|IDPROD | ID_CARAC | NOME      |  
+-------+----------+-----------+
|   1   |     1    | Caneta    |
+-------+----------+-----------+
|   1   |     2    | Caneta    |
+-------+----------+-----------+
|   1   |     3    | Caneta    |
+-------+----------+-----------+
|   1   |     4    | Caneta    |
+-------+----------+-----------+
|   1   |     5    | Caneta    |
+-------+----------+-----------+
|   2   |     1    | Lapiseira |
+-------+----------+-----------+
|   2   |     2    | Lapiseira |
+-------+----------+-----------+
|   2   |     3    | Lapiseira |
+-------+----------+-----------+
|   2   |     4    | Lapiseira |
+-------+----------+-----------+
|   2   |     5    | Lapiseira |
+-------+----------+-----------+
```

Meu objetivo real é listar apenas os produtos, de fato eu não exibo na tela essas características, listo apenas o nome dos produtos, porém utilizo filtros e esses filtros vão de acordo com essas características que tenho no BD. E até onde eu sei, para que eu possa fazer um `WHERE ID_CARAC = '1'`.

Se eu fizesse um WHERE com uma unica condição ficaria tudo bem, porque estaria me retornando só um elemento com base no exemplo, porém posso uso várias condições, algo como:

```
WHERE
    ID_CARAC = 1
    OR
    ID_CARAC = 2
```

E isso faz com que na hora do `foreach` o produto "Caneta" e "Lapiseira" seja listado mais de uma vez, sendo que pra mim já bastaria exibi-los uma unica vez.

> Como posso evitar essa duplicação, ou como posso apagar as linhas repetidas com base no ID do produto na hora do select antes mesmo de formar o array final e me retornar o resultado.

Comment: Poste aqui TODA a query que vc está usando hoje, e não apenas a clausula WHERE.

Comment: Experimente com ... GROUP BY produtos.id

Comment: Olhando por alto a pergunta veria a possibilidade de tirar esse ID_CARAC das colunas retornadas pela query e usar DISTINCT para não pegar as linhas duplicadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que você descreveu, apenas utiliza o produto para fazer um filtro, portanto não há necessidade de mostrar as características. Sendo assim o ideal é que você não utilize nenhum tipo de `JOIN` e sim a cláusula `EXISTS` no seu `WHERE`:

```
SELECT prod.ID,
       prod.NOME
  FROM PRODUTOS prod
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT rel.ID_CARAC
                FROM RELACAO rel
               WHERE rel.ID_PROD = prod.ID
                 AND rel.ID_CARAC IN (1, 2))
```

Como você explicou que de fato não mostra nenhuma informação de característica e apenas filtra por elas, um `EXISTS` terá o efeito desejado.

> [EXISTS Condition](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/exists.php)
>
> The MySQL EXISTS condition is used in combination with a subquery and is considered "to be met" if the subquery returns at least one row.

Em tradução livre:

> [Condição EXISTS](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/exists.php)
>
> A condição EXISTS do MySQL é usada combinada com a subquery e é considerada "a ser cumprida" se a subquery retornar pelo menos um registro.

Comment: Funcionou PERFEITAMENTE!! Exatamente o que eu precisava! Ajudou muito irmão!

Answer (score 0):

> Meu objetivo real é listar apenas os produtos, de fato eu não exibo na tela essas características, listo apenas o nome dos produtos, porém utilizo filtros...

Se eu entendi certo, o que você quer é listar os produtos que possuam determinadas características, sem duplicá-los no resultado.

```
select 

distinct A.id_prod
,B.nome

from relacao as A

left join produtos as B on B.id = A.id_prod

where A.id_carac in (1,2)
```

> SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d3519/2