# Repetir condição no WHERE no momento da query

Tags: mysql, sql, where

Atualmente uso `WHERE coluna IN (1,2,3,4)` na minha consulta. Só que percebi que o `IN` funciona como uma especie de "OR", isso me gera um pequeno problema, pois os `ID` são características de um produto. Essas características são selecionadas em um menu, e passo o id para dentro desse IN.

Exemplo:
Digamos que eu tenha um menu com as seguintes características:

```
MARCA
    Volks 2 ITENS

COR
    BRANCA 1 ITEM
    AZUL 1 ITEM
```

Se eu selecionar `AZUL`, o menu fica da seguinte maneira :

```
MARCA
    Volks 1 ITENS

COR
    AZUL 1 ITEM
```

Ótimo, afinal é exatamente esse tipo de filtro que quero fazer, o problema vem agora, pois se eu clicar em `VOLKS`, consequentemente vou ter dois filtros, "COR: Azul" e "MARCA: Volks", e de acordo com o menu, só um produto se encaixa nesses parâmetros, seria como reafirmar o resultado.

```
MARCA
    Volks 1 ITENS

COR
    AZUL 1 ITEM
```

Só que por causa do IN, parece que ele faz um tipo de "OR" nos id das características, mesmo com dois parâmetros o resultado volta a ser:

```
MARCA
    Volks 2 ITENS

COR
    BRANCA 1 ITEM
    AZUL 1 ITEM
```

Em vez de usar o `IN`

Seria possível usar

```
    coluna = 1
AND
    coluna = 2
AND
    coluna = 3
AND
    coluna = 4
```

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é contar os registros da `subquery` de resposta da sua [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183236/apagar-registro-que-est%C3%A1-sendo-duplicado-na-query-com-o-inner-join?noredirect=1#comment379389_183236) da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT prod.ID,
       prod.NOME
  FROM PRODUTOS prod
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(rel.ID_CARAC)
          FROM RELACAO rel
         WHERE rel.ID_PROD = prod.ID
           AND rel.ID_CARAC IN (1, 2, 3, 4)) = 4
```

Note que removi o `EXISTS` e passei a contar o número de registros, que deve bater com o número de características que você está porcurando.

Não é a melhor solução, mas acho que pra fazer do jeito certo você teria que criar essas características como colunas. Teria, por exemplo, uma coluna cor, uma coluna marca, etc...

Answer (score -2):

Você pode também usar concatenação. 
Por exemplo, caso click em Marca uma string " ... and marca = voks " é adicionada no final da query. Logo, com os dois clicks,  haveria " and marca = voks and cor = azul ". O where pode ser inicializado assim "where 1 = 1 "; Consultas com IN ou Exists degradam a performance, dependendo do caso.

Comment: Ele explicou que não tem uma coluna `marca` no sistema dele. Dê um exemplo prático, só falar por cima não adianta muito.